# I can't install skype no matter what i do

Tags: skype

i am trying to install skype 32bit version, i also tried 64, but after clicking install, the button will change to installing, but after a few seconds it changes back to install.
I have been doing research for hours, and i cannot install it even from the terminal.
I tried every possible command i just keep getting error after error.

Comment: skype is no longer 32 bit.... and 64bit require a 64 bit system

Comment: What does that mean? I can only install the 64bit? So if my system is not 64bit i cannot install skype?

Comment: correct 64-bit only

Comment: Then i must reinstall my OS, or get a higher version of it? Do you know any good way to do it? Or if my pc can have it...

Comment: There is no way to install software designed for 64 bit hardware on a system designed for 32 bit hardware. If you want to install skype, you must get a new PC designed for 64 bit.

Comment: skype is a properietary microsoft product now right, so it is not really surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your system is 64-bit. You cannot install Skype on a 32-bit OS.
2. Make sure your system is up to date before installing.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```
3. Be sure you're using the latest [Skype for Linux](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/?type=weblinux-deb).
4. Try installing using `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb` in terminal.

Comment: When i sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb i get an error processing the archive the architeture of the package (amd64) doesn't match the system (i386)

Comment: @DanielSantos I think you missed step 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use skype online, via your web browser.  But do not use Firefox, since it wants to install a plugin, which also only exists in 64 bit.  You can use Chromium, which can be installed through Software.  Go to [web.skype.com](https://web.skype.com).  I can not judge the quality of this solution.